# Odd RTCReporting bug

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I'm developing an iOS app and my AVQueuePlayer is causing issues.  As it plays, this error appears:

```
RTCReporting: resolve from https://qtpartners.apple.com/storebags/hls?version=1.32
RTCReporting: environment release doesn't exist in storebag
```

I have absolutely no idea what this means.  I'm also noticing, with my AVQueuePlayer, the first item plays fine, the second waits a second before starting then starts from the 1 second mark, and the third doesn't play at all.  These could be related.  Does anyone have any insight on the errors or the playback issues.

Comment: I have this error too, did you figure out what the problem was? @SamBaumgarten

Comment: Still haven't figured it out.  I ended up not using AVQueuePlayer

Answer (score 0):

I met this bug when trying play video on simulator.
Just remove "All Exceptions" breakpoint - This bug will be gone.

Comment: This worked for me so thanks. I'd love to know why this is the case though. It doesn't appear to throw an exception, at least their is know clear error message.